# Can't get input containing spaces in C++

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I have the following `C++` code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct data
{
    char   name1[20];
    string name2[20];
    string name3;
};

void main() {
    data *d = new data;

    cout << "Enter name1 : ";
    cin >> d->name1;        // this does not capture spaces in between

    cout << "Enter name2 : ";
    cin.getline(d->name2,20);   
    //compiler: cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string [20]' to 'char *'

    cin.getline(d->name2,sizeof(d->name2));  // same as above
    getline(cin,d->name2);  
    // error C2665: 'std::getline' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all arguments type

    cout << "Enter name3 : " ;
    cin >> noskipws >> d->name3;  
    // does not even wait for input, execution resumes without my input


    cout << "name1=" << d->name1 << endl;  
    cout << "name2=" << d->name2 << endl;
    cout << "name3=" << d->name3 << endl;


}
```

If I run the above program (commenting lines that cause the compiler to complaint), I would get something like this: (my input italized)

> Enter name1: *ahmad mutawa*
>
> Enter name2: *any name*
>
> Enter name3:
>
> name1=ahmad
>
> name2=
>
> name3=ahmad

What am I doing wrong? How can I get a string containing spaces into a string variable?

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler `cl` from command line tools.

**Edit**
I rewrote the program as recommended from the comments/answers:
I re-declared variables all as strings, without specifying length.

```
struct data
{
    string name1,name2,name3;
};
...
cout << "Enter name1 : ";
getline(cin, d->name1);

cout << "Enter name2 : ";
getline(cin, d->name2);

cout << "Enter name3 : ";
getline(cin, d->name3);
...
```

The program allowed me to input a full name at each `getline` but the output I got contained only the last names, not one of them had the first name or the spaces in between.

Comment: `string name2[20];` -- An array of 20 strings?

Comment: I meant a string of length 20 characters @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: I am new to c++ @1blustone

Comment: That is not how you set one string to 20 characters.  You declared 20 separate strings.  You also don't need to use `new` to create an object in C++.

Comment: @Ahmad if you want a string of length 20 character you can do it by char name2[20];   or using string name2(20,'');

Comment: @ash12 that would still not solve the problem of capturing space characters

Comment: @ash12 -- It would be better to not promote char array usage.

Comment: @Ahmad -- First, a `std::string` is **dynamic**.   I don't think you're understanding this concept, given the code you've written.  A single `std::string` can be resized to 20 characters. What you did was declare an array of `std::string`,i.e. 20 dynamic strings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie please read my edit..

Comment: why are you calling getline three times on the same `d->name2`?

Comment: @Ahmad *without specifying length* -- No, you never declared any "length" with a string.  What you did was declare an array.  Seems you're still not getting the point.  If you want to size a string, you use `resize`, or you add characters to the `std::string`, or you construct a `std::string` of that size.  What you did, again, is declare an array of 20 empty strings.

Comment: @fedepad if you read the comments you will understand that I tried the code and the compiler would not allow that line of code. I said that I had to comment the lines giving me these issues.

Comment: I checked your code and it seems to work in my case. Maybe I paste it in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should know what your original `struct` means:

```
struct data
{
    char   name1[20];  // an array of 20 single characters
    string name2[20];  // an array of 20 dynamic strings
    string name3;      // a single dynamic string
};
```

Look at the `name2` member variable.  It is an *array* of 20 `std::string`.  That means you can have 20 separate dynamic strings, and each string is accessed by `name2[0]`, `name2[1]`, `name2[2]`, up until `name2[19]`.

Given that, since you want to simply enter 3 strings, then the struct above does not reflect what you are trying to accomplish.  The correction should be:

```
struct data
{
    string name1; 
    string name2; 
    string name3; 
};
```

Having done this, then to fill each string from `std::cin`, and include spaces within each string, use `std::getline` 3 times:

```
data d;

getline(cin, d.name1);
getline(cin, d.name2);
getline(cin, d.name3);
```

Here is a [Live Example](http://ideone.com/U9GtQB).

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the declaration

```
string name2[20];
```

does not work normally. Declare it just like

```
string name2;
```

And

```
getline(cin, d->name2);
```

will work perfectly fine

[working_code](http://ideone.com/TUoqjG)

Comment: I was just writing it down... This should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: You should explain what `name2[20]` actually means;  That seems to be the basic issue with the OP's understanding of arrays and objects.

Comment: I tried that. Still, I did not get a chance to input my string.

Comment: @Ahmad , can you post your code to ideone.com , and share the link here. It will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [getline(string)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

It accepts an "std::string". In your case, try

```
getline(cin, d->name3);
# enter a string with a space
cout << "name3=" << d->name3 << endl;
```

Comment: This will only capture the last name, not the first and not the space before the last name

Comment: It is because you still want to get input for the previous "cin".
Remove other "cin" operations .

Another thing, if you allocate your data in the heap using `data* d = new data;`, you should delete the pointer when you no longer need it.
`delete d;
d = NULL;
`